# Image pyramid has wrong colors in GeoServer

Tags: raster, geoserver

I'm fairly new to GeoServer.

I have managed to create an image pyramid out of a ~7 GB ECW file. The files are fine looking at them in explorer but when I import the pyramid and open it in geoexplorer it has wrong colors. This maybe because the image pyramid has alpha channels (i've worked with files without alpha channels before without problems).

Is there a setting I am missing or something like that?

This is one tile from the pyramid and how the raster is supposed to look like:

[image]

This is how it looks like showing the image in Geoserver:

[image]

And here is a print screen of the layer settings:

[image]